# Show that function is continuous at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$,

$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^2+1}$ is continuous at $x_0=-1$. So if $|x+1|<\delta$, then $|f(x)+1| < \epsilon$.

I rearranged $|f(x)+1|=|\frac{(x-1) +(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}|=|\frac{x+x^2}{x^2+1}|=|\frac{1+x}{x+ \frac{1}{x}}|$, but now I'm stuck. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use that $\displaystyle\left|\frac{x+x^2}{x^2+1}\right|=\frac{|x||x+1|}{x^2+1}<|x+1|$ for all x, since $|x|<x^2+1$

because $x^2<(x^2+1)^2=x^4+2x^2+1$ for all x.

Comment: Both polynomials $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ have negative discriminant, so they only assume positive values. Therefore $x^2-|x|+1>0$, for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^2$ is always nonnegative, $1 + x^2\ge 1$. Inverting, this leads to

$$\left|\frac{x^2 + x}{x^2 + 1}\right| = |x| |x + 1| \cdot \frac{1}{|1 + x^2|} \le |x||x + 1|$$

Now you may assume without loss of generality that $|x| \le 2$, since $x$ is close to $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use calculus to compute the minimum value of $$x+\frac1x$$ on the interval $[-2,-1/2]$, call this $m$. Then for $\epsilon > 0$, then for $|x+1| < m^{-1} \epsilon = \delta$ you win since $$| \frac{1+x}{x+1/x} | < |1+x|m^{-1}$$